# Crane is not working while using the Process Modeling Library in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I just want to move the agent using a crane once it's assembled.

I am using the "moveByCrane" block (material handling library) after the "Assembler" block (process modelling library). Now, when I build the mode, it displays two errors, which are shown below in the image.

[image]

Moreover when I run the this model and agent reach at the "Move by crane" block, model through this error.
[image]

Comment: simple, you cannot move something with a crane if you don't have a crane... that's what anylogic is telling you

Comment: but i already set the crane called "crane1". if you see first image 'properties' section, I set the crane with "crane1". Let me know if I am missing some thing.

Comment: is your agent that exists the assembler of type Material Item?

Comment: no it is not Material Item.

Comment: it should be to use material handling library

Comment: in Assembler I change the New Agent to "Material Item Type" agent but the error is still he same.

Comment: I make new model and run in it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Material Handling library, an agent exit by the assembler must be of the type "Material Item." Moreover, the agent in the crane (jib or overhead crane) must match the agent that is exiting the assembler.